# Google charts : How to resize whole chart with svg element on data changes while data greter than 1200 rows

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to draw the google chart while it's having a small amount of data it is drawing successfully while data increase the chart is also increasing more and more can anyone help me to solve the chart and get the same and constant size chart while data increases or decreases.

here is the code that I am trying

```
cCallData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(callsClassifications);
        cCallChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartlive'));
        var chartWidth = cCallData.getNumberOfRows() * 5;
        cbarOptions = {
            isStacked: true,
            annotations: { alwaysOutside: true },
            legend: { position: 'top' },
            height: 300,
            width: chartWidth,
            //bar: { groupWidth: 20 },
            //chartArea: { left: 10 }
        };

        cCallChart.draw(cCallData, cbarOptions);
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

to set the width to something constant, change the following line of code...

```
var chartWidth = cCallData.getNumberOfRows() * 5;
```

to some number of pixels...

```
var chartWidth = 400;
```

or a percentage of the chart container's width...

```
var chartWidth = '100%';
```